# The resource can not be found MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two textboxes and a button (@HTML.ActionLink) on the **Login** view and I want to open the **page** view, in which depending on the username and password written in this textboxes I get the corresponding user from the database and pass it in **page** view to see details about this user.

I have the **resource cannot be found** problem. when this problem appears in the browser, the link is modified so (I think problem would be here):

```
http://localhost:50105/Users/LoginPage?Length=5
```

this is my button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "LoginPage", "Users", new { @class = "btn btn-default", @style = "Color:red" })
```

this is my **LoginPage** action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginPage([Bind(Include = "UserName,Password")] User user)
{
   var per = db.Users.Where
       (x => x.Password == user.Password && x.UserName == user.UserName)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        return View("Page",per);
}
```

this is my **Page** View:

```
@model MVCProject.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page";
}

<h2>Page</h2>

<div>
    <h4>User</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
```

this is my **user** class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

this is my **RegisterRoutes** method in **RouteConfig** class:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

this is my **Login** view:

```
@model MVCProject.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

</br>
<h2 align="Center">Login</h2>



<div>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>

    <div align="center">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new 
{ @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "UserName" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </br>

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
@class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "Password", @type="password"} })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = 
"text-danger" })

    </br>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" align="center">
        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "LoginPage", "Users", new { @class = "btn btn-default", @style = "Color:red" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly its `@Html.ActionLink("Login", "LoginPage", "Users", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default", @style = "Color:red" })` (note the 4th parameter). But your link make no sense - that is making a GET and is not passing any values. You need a submit button to post your form - `<input type="submit" value="Save" />`

Comment: what is your controller name?

Comment: my Controller Name is UsersController

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  - with action link POST isn't possible?

Comment: In fact your view does not even have a `<form>`! You need to enclose you form controls in a `<form>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke is correct.you are not sending your view model values to controller, that will be done by making a button of submit type.

Comment: No its not - it makes a GET,  not a POST. But even you POST method makes no sense since all you doing is getting data

Comment: I will change it with input and try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put your controls inside a form and make a button of type submit to post your model data to controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginPage", "Users", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div align="center">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new 
    { @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "UserName" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </br>

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
    @class = "form-control", @placeHolder = "Password", @type="password"} })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = 
    "text-danger" })

        </br>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" align="center">
           <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: it works, but the data isn't shown in the Page view. Only DisplayNameFor (i.e UserName and Password, not corresponding values) appears.

Comment: are you getting values in per while returning through controller.just debug the par variable.

Comment: it does not works even when I create object in LoginPage action method and pass in View() method

Comment: Users obj = new Users(); obj.FirstName = "abc"; obj.LastName = "xyz";  return View("Page",obj); try this in the contoller

Comment: on the other hand the LoginPage's user parameter is empty - it means that my binding not works

Comment: It seems that I have two problems: 1. I can get username and password in LoginPage's parameter and 2. when I pass object (which has values) in View() I see nothing in the corresponding View

Comment: see my above comment and try that in the controller and comment your code

Comment: User user1 = new User { FirstName = "ggg", LastName = "kkk", Password = "ll", UserName="DDD", UserID = 2 };
            return View("Page",user1);

Comment: no, now somehow it started working but, I can not get userName and password from LoginPage action method's parameter

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("LoginPage", "Users", FormMethod.Post))

Comment: great! happy coding.